# Apollo Client Query on Parameter Function Returns Undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am querying the following Query using useQuery react hook

```
query blogs($id: ID!) {
    blog(id: $id) {
      id
        }
  }
```

Looking at the HTTP request shows a legitimate response but in the code
useQuery returns an undefined data with no error & loading.

```
<Query query={BLOGPOST_CONTENT_QUERY} variables={{ "id": 1 }}>
            {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return <div>Fetching</div>
            if (error) return <div>Error</div>

            const blogs = data.blogs
            console.log(error)
            console.log(loading)
            console.log(data)
```

Is it a bug? what's wrong with the query? if I don't accept any parameters, Apollo gives me data

Comment: I think your id is nested too deep in the variables.  Try `variables = {id: 1}`

Comment: @SeamusR same result

Comment: How does your resolver look like?

Comment: @dario i didn't implement any resolvers

Comment: @dario got to say - this works if I change the query to any query that does not receive a parameter. Reading more about resolvers

Comment: `data` can be undefined at first render .... `if(!data || loading) return <Fetching />`

Comment: @xadm it is always undefined tho

Comment: check response in dev tools/network

Comment: @xadm i got a response back from the grapql server. Anyway, I left apollo and ill be using axios for direct REST http communication

Comment: You can use axios with graphql endpoint using json like from postman